# Attempting to add to database, but ignore duplicates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add data from a CSV into a UNIQUE field, but having an issue where if there is any duplicate in the CSV the program doesn't commit. What I want to happen is if there is a duplicate you are trying to add, simply continue with the rest but do commit at the end. I'm using SQLalchemy. It's almost as if db encounters an error it doesn't commit whatsoever even if I do have the try/except.

```
import csv
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
# scoped session allows us to have multiple users on a database
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    # id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM authors WHERE name='Anne Rice'")
    # print(id['id'])
    with open("books.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            # :placeholder, and then provide variables 
            try:
                db.execute("INSERT INTO authors1 (name) VALUES (:name)",
                            {"name":row['author']})
            except:
                pass
            print("added",row['author'])

        db.commit()
```

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy, I think someone else asked but deleted the comment

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/WxHY6KAS) works for me.

Comment: Does it commit to the database? The code works, it prints added, but something about throwing an exception makes the db not commit at the end. I need to find a way to fail silently is what I've read

Comment: Replace `except:` with `except Exception as e:` and on the next line replace `pass` with `print(e)`. Does that output give you some insight as to what is actually failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version of your example, and it works, it'll go over the authors list and add them to the database, and when the database gives an IntegrityError because of non-unique values, it will print it and move on.

NB. I put the same "print added" at the same level as you and it will print both the authors that are added and the ones that were skipped.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)

with engine.begin() as con:
    con.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE author ("
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        "name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)"
        )

authors = [
    "Guillaume Apollinaire",
    "Jules Verne",
    "Jean-Paul Sartre",
    "Jules Verne",
]

with engine.begin() as con:
    for author in authors:
        try:
            con.execute(
                "INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (:name)",
                {"name": author}
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        print(f"added {author}")

with engine.connect() as con:
    print(con.execute("SELECT * FROM author").all())
```

gives:

```
2022-06-04 11:53:26,812 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-06-04 11:53:26,813 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine CREATE TABLE author (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)
2022-06-04 11:53:26,813 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-06-04 11:53:26,816 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2022-06-04 11:53:29,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-06-04 11:53:29,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (:name)
2022-06-04 11:53:29,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {'name': 'Guillaume Apollinaire'}
added Guillaume Apollinaire
2022-06-04 11:53:29,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (:name)
2022-06-04 11:53:29,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {'name': 'Jules Verne'}
added Jules Verne
2022-06-04 11:53:29,951 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (:name)
2022-06-04 11:53:29,951 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {'name': 'Jean-Paul Sartre'}
added Jean-Paul Sartre
2022-06-04 11:53:29,951 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (:name)
2022-06-04 11:53:29,951 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {'name': 'Jules Verne'}
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: author.name
[SQL: INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (:name)]
[parameters: {'name': 'Jules Verne'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
added Jules Verne
2022-06-04 11:53:29,960 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2022-06-04 11:59:34,511 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT * FROM author
2022-06-04 11:59:34,511 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
[(1, 'Guillaume Apollinaire'), (2, 'Jules Verne'), (3, 'Jean-Paul Sartre')]
```

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use an actual database file instead of a `:memory:` database?

Comment: @GordThompson Both SQLite file and PostgreSQL work the same, `sqlite3.IntegrityError` and `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation`. edit: postgres does not work, selecting returns empty list.

Comment: Hmm, okay. When I tested yesterday I was getting different errors, but I may have been testing against the current main branch of SQLAlchemy which is (or will become) version 2.0. I just tested against version 1.4.37 and `sqlite:///C:/Users/gord/Desktop/so72483547.sqlite` does seem to work.